# Sorting in yii Cdbcriteria with sum(amount)

Tags: php, yii

I need to show highest amount on the top in yii Cgridview.

I have two models: `members` and `billing`, 
          member_id is foregion key in billing model.
My Model Function:

```
   public function getImportantMembers(){       
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;        
    $criteria->select ='t.*,b.billing_id,b.amount,b.billing_date,b.member_id,b.billing_status , sum(b.amount) AS totalamount';      
    $criteria->join = 'JOIN billing AS b ON b.member_id = t.id ';
    $criteria->addCondition("b.billing_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 MONTH)  AND b.billing_status='c' AND b.amount > 150 ");               
    $criteria->group  = 't.id';        
    $criteria->order = " totalamount DESC";                   

    return new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this),array(
        'pagination'=>array(            
            'pageSize'=> Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize',Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),),          
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

but this function not showing correctly highest amount at the top or amount DESC
How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Define relations in your models and use them in your criteria. Then pass a CSort object to the DataProvider like below. You can define custom sort parameters as long as you define them in your model.

```
return new CActiveDataProvider( 'Model', array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
            ...........
            ...........

            '*',
        ),
    ),
));
```

For details this link will help. 
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/

If that link doesn't help post your model codes for both the tables and I'll try to provide some example code.